# Parallel API requests using Single.zip not handling all errors

Tags: rx-java2

I want to fetch data from two API requests parallelly.

```
Single<TodayDataEntry> todayDataEntrySingle = openWeatherApi.getTodayData(
            "London,uk", FetchDataUtil.API_KEY).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

Single<ListWrapper<ForecastDataEntry>> forecastDataEntrySingle = openWeatherApi.getForecastData(
            "London,uk", FetchDataUtil.API_KEY).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

Single<DataAll> observable = Single.zip(
        todayDataEntrySingle,
            forecastDataEntrySingle,(t1, t2) -> {
                return new DataAll(t2.getList(), t1);
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

1. After subscribing, if both API requests fail (like in case where there is no internet connection), one of the error signals is not handled (even though `onError` is getting called), causing app to crash.

   However if I use `Observable<>` instead of `Single<>`, the error is handled
   and an exception is not thrown. Is something wrong in my
   implementation?
2. If I don't call `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io)` for individual observables and instead just call for zipped one, the exception is not thrown. However as far as I know, in this case the API requests are not in parallel.

Comment: `zip` can only deliver one error at most, the other one is routed to the global error handler. [Install a global error handler to avoid crashing](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling). `Observable`s have longer code paths and your failure in the first source may completely prevent the subscription to the second one, hence no crash.

Comment: @akarnokd: How could I handle that?

Comment: Please read the linked wiki section.

Comment: @akarnokd: Thanks! It worked. PCMIIW: I think that in second case of question, since the observables will be executed synchronously, only one time error is delivered.

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh How did you fix this issue? Updating the library did the work?

Comment: @ASN I used global error handler. Look at the link provided by akarnokd.

Answer (score 0):

We were facing the exact same issue with `Completable.mergeArray()` and it literally took us years to figure this out. In summary, the crash is caused by the streams running in parallel and throwing an error at the same time.

We wrote an extensive [blog post series](https://proandroiddev.com/merging-rxjava-observables-considered-harmful-part-i-fdaaaa3364c5) describing the issue and our workaround. I think it'll definitely help if you take a look. Let me know in the comments if you have any questions.